# Query to get weekly average spending each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i'm have question..
i have database mostly like this,
how can i get weekly average of spendings from each customer? can you show me the sql query to this?

here the example

```
| customer   | spending | date                |
| -----------|----------|---------------------|
| customer A |      105 | 2016-03-02 11:24:38 |
| customer A |       75 | 2016-02-02 11:24:38 |
| customer B |       35 | 2016-03-02 11:24:38 |
| customer A |       40 | 2016-03-02 11:24:38 |
| customer B |      105 | 2016-02-15 11:24:38 |
| customer A |      100 | 2016-03-02 11:24:38 |
| customer A |      150 | 2016-02-21 11:24:38 |
| customer A |      139 | 2016-03-02 11:24:38 |
```

and more...

anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `GROUP BY` on the combination of customer and week of the year:

```
SELECT customer, WEEK(date), AVG(spending)
FROM sales
GROUP BY customer, WEEK(date)
```